# EF Core Code First with Identity differences between migrations on different machines

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

We keep getting migrations that include changes to the ASP.NET Identity tables on one computer, but not on the other when a developer goes to create a migration.

We're using:

- EF Core 3.1.3
- .NET Identity Core
- Package Manager Console `Add-Migration <Name>`
- Visual Studio 2019 16.5.2
- `dotnet ef` reports `Entity Framework Core .NET Command-line Tools 3.1.3`

We thought we had this fixed last time it started happening by:

- Updating our EF Core Tools to the same versions
- Updating Visual studio to the same versions
- Deleting all migrations
- Creating a new initial migration

But today it appeared again.  On one machine `Add-Migration` wants to make these changes to the Identity tables while the other does not:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "Name",
    table: "AspNetUserTokens",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "LoginProvider",
    table: "AspNetUserTokens",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "ProviderKey",
    table: "AspNetUserLogins",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "LoginProvider",
    table: "AspNetUserLogins",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
```

Comment: Looks like one of the machines has [StoreOptions.MaxLengthForKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.storeoptions.maxlengthforkeys?view=aspnetcore-3.1) set to 128

Comment: @IvanStoev Aha!  Ok, that's definitely it.  Changing `Startup.cs` `AddDefaultIdentity` to explicitly set that value "fixed" the issue.  But now my question is how would that be different between two machines running the same source?  Is that default value stored somewhere on the machine itself?

Comment: Identity is using [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1), so I guess it's coming from appsettings.json or something - probably you know better.

Answer (score 1):

I never found out how or why the default value was different between two machines, but I did find out how to override it in code. You can set the `MaxLengthForKeys` when registering Identity in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.Stores.MaxLengthForKeys = 128;
})
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

There's also a related discussion about it here:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14503